# Node.js integration test + database

Tags: javascript, node.js, integration-testing, mocha.js

I have a small REST API written in node.js and tested with Mocha.

My goal is to test the CRUD funtionality and verify the values in the underlying database too (MySQL). In theory I have to load a databade fixture, execute the request from the test framework and tell the framework to check what's in the MySQL database (server side).

Is there an elegant node way to do this?
In php I would do it with http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db or simiilar.

Thank you,
Tibor

Answer (score -2):

You can use chrome extension POSTMAN to test your REST api
Link for extension
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en